# Trouble freeing all my memory

Tags: c, free

I am quite new to C and am having a hard to grasping full understanding of pointers
The current task at hand is clearing every single array from the struct Commands (the struct is shown on the bottom).
Hopefully someone can identify something horribly wrong like freeing something multiple times.  I know my code might look horrid but thanks for taking the time to look at it.
My current attempt at clearing everything:

```
void clear_commands(Commands *commands) {
  Command *compile, *test, *temp;
  if (commands != NULL) {
    compile = commands->compile;
    while (compile != NULL) {
      temp = compile;
      compile = compile->next;
      free(temp);
    }

    test = commands->test;
    while (test != NULL) {
      temp = test;
      test = test->next;
      free(temp);
    }

    free(commands);
    commands = NULL;
  }
}
```

These are the typedefs:

```
typedef struct Command{
  char *command;
  struct Command *next;
} Command;

typedef struct {
  Command *test;
  Command *compile;
} Commands;
```

ADDED: read_commands

```
Commands read_commands(const char *compile_cmds, const char *test_cmds) {
  FILE *f;
  Commands *commands = malloc(sizeof(Commands));
  Command *compile, *test;
  char temp[257];

  if (compile_cmds == NULL || test_cmds == NULL)
    exit(0);

  compile = malloc(sizeof(Command));
  test = malloc(sizeof(Command));
  commands->compile = compile;
  commands->test = test;

  f = fopen(compile_cmds,"r");
  if (f != NULL)
    while(!feof(f)) {
      if(fgets(temp, 257, f) != NULL) {
        compile = malloc(sizeof(Command));
        compile->command = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
        strcpy(compile->command, temp);
        compile->next = malloc(sizeof(Command));
        compile = compile->next;
      }
    }
  fclose(f);
  ...
  return *commands;
}
```

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I am leaking when I call this function  
I do not free commands->compile and commands->test even though i thought i did

Comment: This function makes no allocations, so this is not where the leak originates. Check the code that builds the `commands` parameter.

Comment: You set `compile->next = NULL` and then, `compile = compile->next`. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: `commands->compile = NULL; /*...*/ compile = commands->compile;` Then `compile->next = NULL; compile = compile->next;` What do you think `commands->compile` will be set to when `read_commands` returns?

Comment: @user007 how do i instantiate it without mallocing because i do not know the size at the time?

Comment: You want `complile->next` to hold the address of the next `command` right??

Comment: @dxiv NULL
however i have malloc() does that not work if it is NULL? (this is probably a fundamental thing that I am not understanding)

Comment: @user007 yeah I guess I am not doing it correctly

Comment: I suggest you run it in a debugger and single step through the code. It's a great way to understand what it's doing. Short answer, yes, you need to malloc each one, but at some point you need to "hookup" your newly created object in the linked list that starts at `commands->compile`.

Comment: Don't keep changing the question - especially in response to answers.  It makes the existing answers look like nonsense, and if you do that continuously the code in the question will end up correct, making your question look like nonsense.

Comment: @Clifford Im sorry Im new to this

Comment: Now with the latest edit you call `malloc(sizeof(Command))` *twice* for each `fgets` line. That alone should raise a red flag. Your comment under @SimonÁdám's answer was correct, by the way.

Comment: @user5514267 : I appreciate that; SO is best used as a straight Q & A system rather then a collaborative debugging platform.  With a relatively large and complex code example such as this, you are likely to get people picking up on things you were not asking about and answers that are only partial solutions to working code.  I suggest you let it run and pick out the helpful parts.  It may be that no one answer can be accepted, because it does not solve all the problems, but tat says more about the question style that the quality of the answers perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

`free(commands->compile);` and `free(commands->test);` are not necessary, you are freeing them in the first loop

---

`clear_commands` is good, the problem is in `read_commands`

```
          commands->compile = NULL; /* use malloc here */
          commands->test = NULL; /* and here */
          compile = commands->compile; /* otherwise you are giving NULL pointer variable to compile */
          test = commands->test; /* Same here */

          f = fopen(compile_cmds,"r");
          if (f != NULL)
            while(!feof(f)) {
                if(fgets(temp, 257, f) != NULL) {
                    compile = malloc(sizeof(Command)); /* this is not necessary */
                    compile->command = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
                    strcpy(compile->command, temp);
                    compile->next = NULL; /* use malloc here */
                    compile = compile->next; /* if not, compile is NULL again */
                }
           }
           fclose(f);

            /*after this add:*/

if (compile == commands->compile) {
    commands->compile = NULL;
}
free(compile);
compile = NULL;
```

same things with the test_cmds

Comment: what I am confused on is mallocing when I do not know if there is a future input.  
for commands->compile = NULL  
should I do commands->compile = malloc(sizeof(command))
and then free it if there is no string input afterwards

Comment: As it is now, there will always be an extra Command at the end of the list, whose `command` and `next` fields are not initialized (so it will most likely crash when trying to free everything).

Comment: Re: the added comment at the end of the code, you still need to check that the `last unnecessary malloc` was not also the first one (for example, if the file couldn't be opened, or was empty) and in that case reset `commands->compile = NULL;` too.

Comment: Answer is refreshed. Thanks dxiv.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I see with your read_commands, which are not exactly correct!

Your `commands->compile` and `commands->test` are always NULL as you set them at the beginning of the code! Creating a new variable `compile = commands->compile` and then running all the code using `compile` does NOT mean that your original `commands->compile` will also be modified. So, after your first `fclose(f);` your `compiles->next` is still `NULL`, because you just did not change it, you changed another variable `compile`.

And this is mistake is there even when you are probably changing `commands->test`, `compile->next`, or `test->next`.

You need to understand that when you copy the value of a `first` pointer in `second` pointer variable, and you change the value of the variable that is pointed by the `second`, the value when accessed using `first` also shows the change.
Example ::

```
int a = 10, *b, *c;
b = &a;
c = a;
*c = 30; // a gets changed
```

It does not mean if you change the `second` itself, that will also change the value pointed by `first`.
Example ::

```
int a = 10, *b, *c, *d, e = 30;
b = &a;
d = &e;
c = b;
c = d; //This does not change a
```

This is something you are trying to do everywhere in your `read_commands` code. I think you can get an idea from this and understand your mistake!

**Edit ::**

A part of the corrected code ::

```
  Command *prev = NULL;
  f = fopen(compile_cmds,"r");
  if (f != NULL)
    while(!feof(f)) {
      if(fgets(temp, 257, f) != NULL) {
        Command *var = malloc(sizeof(Command));
        var->command = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
        var->next = NULL;
        strcpy(var->command, temp);
        if(prev == NULL) {
            compile = var;
            prev = compile;
        } else {
            prev->next = var;
            prev = var;
        }
      }
    }
    commands->compile = compile;
```

Comment: Plus a `temp->next = NULL;` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
Commands read_commands(const char *compile_cmds, const char *test_cmds) {
  FILE *f;
  Commands *commands = malloc(sizeof(Commands));
  Command *compile, *test;
  char temp[257];

  if (compile_cmds == NULL || test_cmds == NULL)
    exit(0);

  compile = malloc(sizeof(Command));
  test = malloc(sizeof(Command));
  commands->compile = compile;
  commands->test = test;

  f = fopen(compile_cmds,"r");
  if (f != NULL)
    while(!feof(f)) {
      if(fgets(temp, 257, f) != NULL) {
        compile->command = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
        strcpy(compile->command, temp);
        compile->next = malloc(sizeof(Command));
        compile = compile->next;
      }
    }
  fclose(f);
  ...
  return *commands;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution is the simplest and easiest to comprehend solution in this case; so long as your lists are not so long that the stack overflows due to the recursion depth:

```
void clear_command_list( Command* cmd_list )
{
    // If this node exists...
    if( cmd_list != NULL )
    {
        // Clear the tail list
        clear_command_list( cmd_list->next ) ;

        // Free command string in this node
        free( cmd_list.command ) ;
        cmd_list.command = NULL ;

        // Free Command node
        free( cmd_list ) ;
        cmd_list = NULL ;
    }
} 

void clear_commands(Commands *commands)
{
    // Delete test list
    clear_command_list( commands->test ) ;

    // Delete compile list
    clear_command_list( commands->compile ) ;

    // Delete the Commands header
    free( commands ) ;
    commands = NULL ;
}
```

Note that setting the pointers to NULL following `free()` protects against heap corruption should the pointer be erroneously free'd again.

Each list can be thought of as a node followed by a smaller list.  The `clear_command_list()` function calls itself with the "smaller" list, then deletes the head data.  The recursion becomes deeper and deeper until it finds the terminating NULL node, the the recursion unwinds deleting each node from the end-backwards.

Even if you do it iteratively, a separate `clear_command_list()` function that can delete both `compile` and `test` lists makes sense rather that repeating the same code with different variables - that is maintenance heavy and error prone.  Get it right *once* and re-use it.  The structure is the same as above (and the `clear_commands()` function identical, only `clear_command_list()` needs to change:

```
void clear_command_list( Command* cmd_list )
{
    Command* next = cmd_list ;

    // For each lode in list
    while( next != NULL )
    {
        Command* node = next ;
        next = node->next ;

        // Free command string in this node
        free( node->command ) ;
        node->command = NULL ;

        // Free Command node
        free( node ) ;
        node = NULL ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note also the open style with plenty of vertical white-space and comments.  I suggest it makes the code easier to read and maintain that your dense "line-saver" style.